# tileserver-gl and leaflet select vector tiles and getfeatureinfo

Tags: leaflet, vector-tiles

Im running tilserver-gl and serving mbtiles. What is the correct  process of adding these tiles to leaflet where I could extract attribute information by selecting polygon for example.
Currently I add layer as png format to display :

```
    var tileUrl4 = 'http://localhost:4545/styles/built_up_areas/512/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';  
    var tileLayer4 = L.tileLayer(tileUrl4, {
    maxZoom: 22,
    attribution: 'Fourth Tile Layer Attribution'
});
```

What format should I add to leaflet map so I could extract attribute information when I click on vector layer.

Thank you .